# Superimposing plots in seaborn cause x-axis to misallign

Tags: python, seaborn, jupyter

I am having an issue trying to superimpose plots with seaborn. I am able to generate the two plots separetly as

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2,figsize=(30, 7))

sns.lineplot(data=data1, y='MSE',x='pct_gc',ax=ax1)

sns.boxplot(x="pct_gc", y="MSE", data=data2,ax=ax2,width=0.4)
```

The output looks like this:
[image: Plots not superimposed]

But when i try to put both plots superimposed, but assiging both to the same ax object.

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2,figsize=(30, 7))

sns.lineplot(data=data1, y='MSE',x='pct_gc',ax=ax1)

sns.boxplot(x="pct_gc", y="MSE", data=data2,ax=ax2,width=0.4)
```

[image: Plots superimposed]

I am not able to identify with the X axis in the Lineplot changes when superimposing both plots (both plots X axis go from 0 to 0.069).

My goal is for both plots to be superimposed, while keeping the same X axis range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seaborn's `boxplot` creates categorical x-axis, with all boxes nicely with the same distance. Internally the x-axis is numbered as `0, 1, 2, ...` but externally it gets the labels from 0 to 0.069.

To combine a line plot with a `boxplot`, matplotlib's `boxplot` can be addressed directly, so that `positions` and `widths` can be set explicitly. When `patch_artist=True`, a rectangle is created (instead of just lines), for which a `facecolor` can be given. `manage_ticks=False` prevents that `boxplot` changes the x ticks and their limits. Optionally `notch=True` would accentuate the median a bit more, but depending on the data, the confidence interval might be too large and look weird.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'pct_gc': np.linspace(0, 0.069, 200), 'MSE': np.random.normal(0.02, 0.1, 200).cumsum()})
data1['pct_range'] = pd.cut(data1['pct_gc'], 10)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(ncols=1, figsize=(20, 7))

sns.lineplot(data=data1, y='MSE', x='pct_gc', ax=ax1)

for interval, color in zip(np.unique(data1['pct_range']), plt.cm.tab10.colors):
    ax1.boxplot(data1[data1['pct_range'] == interval]['MSE'],
                positions=[interval.mid], widths=0.4 * interval.length,
                patch_artist=True, boxprops={'facecolor': color},
                notch=False, medianprops={'color':'yellow', 'linewidth':2},
                manage_ticks=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]